# Terraform Import and Using Gitlab CI/CD - Failing when used within Gitlab

Tags: amazon-s3, import, terraform, bucket

I'm trying to apply S3 Bucket Lifecycle policy to all our existing S3 buckets.

Upon testing on my on AWS account and using terraform to apply lifecycle to existing S3 bucket with terraform import, it is working fine as expected.

Upon using it on actual deployment with Gitlab yml file, terraform import is successful however plan states it will still the existing resource as opposed to just importing current settings.

Below are sample plan output when initializing terraform import

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any advice on how to best approach this kind of terraform init and import when using it with Gitlab

Comment: Importing it is a one time action that will bring the resource into the state. You don't want to do this in CI/CD as that will be repetitive and fail after the first time. It would be useful if you could edit your question to show your Terraform files and what you're trying to achieve more widely. You should also replace your screenshots with text that people can more easily read and parse.

Comment: Screenshots are just supporting documents. 

To also add, tested uploading tfstate file manually and using it still won't work. 

Also executed once terraform import and next run without it so somehow tf plan  still didn't recognize the existing buckets.

One time terraform import worked on my end just on my own personal AWS account and local terraform without CI CD. 

Work AWS account + Gitlab + Terraform Import seems to be have no clean approach yet as of this time when all are integrated.